# Data not being written to Database ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, insert

I am building a Forum in ASP.Net but have a small problem.

I have 1 user who creates a topic and can write a post to it fine, but if another user logs in, it won't insert the post into the database. It's returning that it does but nothing inserts. The original user can login and still post but no-one else can.

this is my code in behind

```
    protected void addPostBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    //Define ADO.NET objects.
    string insertSQL;
    string topic = Request.QueryString["topicid"].ToString();
    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO Posts (TopicID, PostBody, PUserID)"
        + "VALUES (@Topic, @NewPostText, @PUserID)";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);

    // Try to open the database and execute the update
    int added = 0;
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", topic);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPostText", newPostText.InnerText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PUserID", Session["User_ID"]);
        con.Open();
        added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblResults.Text = "Your post has been added";
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblResults.Text = "Error inserting record. " + err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    if (added > 0)
    {
        this.BindRepeater();
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors at all. It says it submitted fine, but it's not in the database unless the original poster does it.

**EDIT:**

Just realized it's to do with my view. This is my current view that it's reading from

```
    SELECT dbo.Posts.PostBody, dbo.Posts.PostDate, dbo.Posts.PostID, dbo.[User].username, dbo.Topic.TopicID
FROM  dbo.Topic RIGHT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Posts ON dbo.Topic.TopicID = dbo.Posts.TopicID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.[User] ON dbo.Topic.TUserID = dbo.[User].UserID AND dbo.Posts.PUserID = dbo.[User].UserID
```

But it's returning NULL now for the other users names

Comment: what does your Posts table look like? is this the same code that the creator of the topic usess when creating a post?

Comment: okay, and what are you trying to do with this view? and why right outer join to start and not left outer join?

Comment: I'm pulling from 3 tables. Just found it it was the user join. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

The view needs to be as follows

```
SELECT     dbo.Posts.PostBody, dbo.Posts.PostDate, dbo.Posts.PostID, dbo.[User].username, dbo.Topic.TopicID
FROM         dbo.Topic LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Posts ON dbo.Topic.TopicID = dbo.Posts.TopicID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.[User] ON dbo.Posts.PUserID = dbo.[User].UserID
```